# Caching Strategy: WCF Buffer pooling and size

Tags: wcf, caching, configuration, azure

I am currently trying to understand the best configuration for caching.  I am using Azure In-Role caching (currently Colocated, but Dedicated at a later point) in a Web Api 2 application in .NET 4.5.1.

The `transportProperties` element in `dataCacheClient` have two seaminly important attributes, `maxBufferPoolSize` and `maxBufferSize`.  I've done a bit of reading on these, most notably [here](http://obsessivelycurious.blogspot.com/) and [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d6e234d3-942f-4e9d-8470-32618d3f3212/maxbufferpoolsize-vs-maxbuffersize?forum=wcf), and it seems like these attributes can play an significant part in performance.

Currently I have different caching scenarios but one `dataCacheClient` to conquer them all:

I understand that this is probably quite horrendous.  After the reading and analysing my caching implemention, I have come to the following plan for each caching scenario.

**Could someone with more knowledge about buffer pooling validate and critique my caching strategy below.**

**Disclaimer:** I am estimating the size of my objects based on their field types.  I understand that this won't be correct. DataCache uses the `NetDataContractSerializer` which implementions some form of XML-based serialisation.

### Many tiny, well-defined objects. Low expiry.

**Scenario:** +-50,000 objects at 16 bytes each.  Very low expiry rate. High read rate (possibly 1000s per request)

The following would cater for all the items:

```
maxBufferPoolSize = 6,400,000 bytes (128 * 50,0000 items)
maxBufferSize = 128 bytes (the items will never exceed 128 bytes and 128 is the smallest pool size available)
```

**Configuration:**

```
<dataCacheClient name="MyTinyObjects">
  <localCache isEnabled="true" sync="NotificationBased" objectCount="50000" ttlValue="30000" />
  <clientNotification pollInterval="300" />
  <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="6400000" maxBufferSize="128" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

Do I actually need to pre allocate pools here since they expire very rarely?  Perhaps maxBufferPoolSize="0" is fine.

Due to a high read rate, I have included a `localCache` to improve read latency.

### Many small objects of varying size.  Medium expiry.

**Scenario:** +-15,000 objects of up too 2048 bytes but mostly around the 256 - 512 bytes.  They expire often as data is invalidated over time.

I should create the following cache:

```
maxBufferPoolSize = 1,280,000 bytes
maxBufferSize = 2048 bytes (the vast majority items should never exceed 2048 bytes)
```

This means there are essentially 10,000 buffers in the 128 pool, 5000 in the 256 pool, and so on until there are 62 buffers in the 2048 pool.

**Configuration:**

```
<dataCacheClient name="MyDynamicObjects">
  <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="1280000" maxBufferSize="2048 " />
</dataCacheClient>
```

### Few very large items. No expiry.

**Scenario:** +-50 objects of 1 mb each.  Preloaded on application start-up and do not expire.

In this case, there is no point setting a maxBufferPoolSize, as there will be no performance improvement  in having available pools as they will not be disposed until the application pool recycling.  Actually, setting this to, let's say, 1048576 will created a lot of unused pools (a waste of memory).

But, maxBufferSize will need to be set above 1 mb (greater than 1,048,576 bytes).

**Configuration:**

```
<dataCacheClient name="MyBulkyObjects">
  <transportProperties maxBufferPoolSize="0" maxBufferSize="1048576" />
</dataCacheClient>
```

Comment: I am sure you can get lots of speculation, but the only accurate answers will be based on testing.

Comment: It's 7 years later I wonder what Dave found out?

Comment: @JohnPeters if only my (human) memory wasn't so volatile!

Comment: Ya, understood, we live in the land of constant interruption, it's amazing we can remember anything. Thanks Dave.